# VueJS: Getting dynamic checkbox values in VueJS 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I am using VueJS 2 and Vuetify to build the subscription form below. Where all the preferences applicable for a subscription are fetched from the server and displayed. Preferences in the image are for digital magazine subscription. For a print magazine subscription preferences might be different.

[image]

The data fetched from server looks like this

```
preferences: [
    {
      id: "1",
      title: "Subscription frequence",
      options: ["Daily", "Weekly", "Fortnight", "Monthly"]
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      title: "Topics",
      options: ["Sports", "Politics", "Art", "Music", "Health", "Tech"]
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      title: "Promotional Offers",
      options: ["Daily", "Weekly", "Fortnight", "Monthly", "Never"]
    }
  ]
```

I have used `v-for` to display preferences like below:

```
<v-col
  v-for="pref in preferences"
  :key="pref.id"
>
  <span>{{ pref.title }}</span>
  <v-checkbox
    v-for="option in pref.options"
    :key="option"
    :v-model="pref.options"
    :label="option"
    color="red"
    value="option"
    hide-details
  >
  </v-checkbox>
</v-col>`
```

Now, since all the preferences have the same `options` array, I am not able figure how to differentiate one checkbox group from another. And therefore get the selected checkbox for each preference group.

Any tips much appreciated. Thanks.

**UPDATE**
This works for `input` type as shown in @palash answer. But is not working for Vuetify `v-checkbox`.

Comment: If the `id` in each preference is unique, then you can try to append this id along with the checkbox value (`:value="pref.id+'-'+option"`) and extract when receiving the selected values.

Answer (score 0):

First, try to add an empty `selected` array to each object inside `preferences` array:

```
preferences: [{
      id: "1",
      title: "Subscription frequence",
      options: ["Daily", "Weekly", "Fortnight", "Monthly"],
      selected: []
   },
   {
      id: "2",
      title: "Topics",
      options: ["Sports", "Politics", "Art", "Music", "Health", "Tech"],
      selected: []
   },
   {
      id: "3",
      title: "Promotional Offers",
      options: ["Daily", "Weekly", "Fortnight", "Monthly", "Never"],
      selected: []
   }
]
```

Next, in the template update the `v-checkbox` model from:

```
:v-model="pref.options"
```

to

```
:v-model="pref.selected"
```

Now, you can easily see the selected options in each preference like:

- For Subscription frequence:

  - `this.preferences[0].selected`
- For Topics:

  - `this.preferences[1].selected`
- For Promotional Offers:

  - `this.preferences[2].selected`

**Simple Demo:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selected: [],
    roles: [{id:1,name:"Client"},{id:2,name:"Admin"},{id:3,name:"Guest"}]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="role in roles" :key="role.id">
    <label>{{role.name}}</label>
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="selected" :value="role"/>
  </div>
  
  <p>Selected Roles:</p>
  {{selected}}
</div>
```

**Complex Demo:**

```js
new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data: {
      preferences: [{
            id: "1",
            title: "Subscription frequence",
            options: ["Daily", "Weekly", "Fortnight", "Monthly"],
            selected: []
         },
         {
            id: "2",
            title: "Topics",
            options: ["Sports", "Politics", "Art", "Music", "Health", "Tech"],
            selected: []
         }
      ]
   }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
   <div v-for="pref in preferences" :key="pref.id">
      <h3>{{pref.title}}:</h3>
      <div v-for="option in pref.options" :key="option">
         <label>{{option}}</label>
         <input type="checkbox" v-model="pref.selected" :value="option" /><br>
      </div>
      <p>Selected {{pref.title}}:</p>
      {{pref.selected}}
      <br><br><hr/>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For some reason, the `selected` array does not populate with selected values. Does this work for you?

Comment: You mean the demo is not working for you. I can clearly see values in UI once I select `Client` checkbox..

Comment: the demo works but in my local it does not. not sure if it is because of vuetify `v-checkbox` behavior.

Comment: I have also added a demo with your `preferences` data. You can see it is also working fine. There might be some issue related to `v-checkbox`. You will need to check the plugin docs for that.

Comment: True, your example works. But the same does not work if we replace `input` element with  Vuetify `v-checkbox`.

Comment: Ok, then you can try to also open a [new issue](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/new/choose) in vuetify github repo for help.

Answer (score 0):

Add a selectedOption key in preferences objects.

```
preferences: [
{
  id: "1",
  title: "Subscription frequence",
  options: ["Daily", "Weekly", "Fortnight", "Monthly"],
  selectedOption: []
},
{
  id: "2",
  title: "Topics",
  options: ["Sports", "Politics", "Art", "Music", "Health", "Tech"],
  selectedOption: []
},
{
  id: "3",
  title: "Promotional Offers",
  options: ["Daily", "Weekly", "Fortnight", "Monthly", "Never"],
  selectedOption: []
}
```

]

```
<v-checkbox
v-for="option in pref.options"
:key="option"
:v-model="pref.selectedOption"
:label="option"
color="red"
value="option"
hide-details
```

>